# Differentiation using Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials

I have task - find derivative (degree N) using Chebyshev polynomials.

My issue is I can't find related theory. Give me a hint (book name, article, example), please.

I'm very appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?  Express your function in a Chebyshev series.  Differentiate term-by-term.  If the coefficients decay rapidly enough, this is justified.

Basically the theory comes from Fourier series: the Chebyshev series of 
$f(x)$ on $[-1,1]$ corresponds to the Fourier series of $f(\cos(x))$ on $[0,\pi]$